# how to suppress android gradle dependencies warnings that not related to the project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

On react native projects we are using java modules from external sources, as follows:

```
.
.
implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
implementation project(':mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl')
.
.
```

sometimes these projects are source of too much warnings as follows:

```
The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018.


Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018


The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Update Build Tools version and sync project
Open File


Configuration 'provided' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'compileOnly'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018


The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018.


Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018


The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Update Build Tools version and sync project
Open File
```

How can I suppress this warnings when I build the project. it annoying and misleading?

Answer (score 0):

Update SDK
https://medium.com/@alberto.schiabel/how-to-permanently-fix-sdk-build-tools-is-too-low-for-project-error-in-react-native-for-android-1a2d245bda18
Change compile to implementation
https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa